# How can I shuffle my songs in IOS 8.4?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, ios

Just now, I upgraded to IOS level 8.4. Not sure if I'm missing something, but I can't seem to figure out how you shuffle songs. I don't see an icon that says shuffle?

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select Songs from the list you want to shuffle.

Select any song in that list to start playback.

Enable shuffle mode, disable repeat. (click the mini player at the bottom of the screen and you will see the option to shuffle)